# Delete a file in Android when you have a path of form `/storage/1018-2710/Pictures/oLvCVPZrNxk.jpg`

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mediastore, android-storage

So I am trying to delete a file from Android External storage, the problem is, I've tried getting the path multiple times in multiple different ways. Using MediaStore Api I've come really close but cannot figure out how to do it.
I cannot get the `EXTERNAL_URI` because the projection requires Strings and `EXTERNAL_URI` on MediaStore returns a URI not a String.

This is how I load images, the GalleryImage class just contains, file path `/storage/1018-2710/Pictures/oLvCVPZrNxk.jpg`, and some booleans to handle selection. I tried adding external URI but failed to do so.

```
public class ImageLoader {
    public ArrayList<GalleryImage> getAllShownImagesPath(Context context) {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name, column_index_content_uri;
        ArrayList<GalleryImage> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        };

        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
         //   String externalURI = cursor.getString();
            String externalURI = ""; //empty,  beacuse I couldnt get it to work...

            listOfAllImages.add(new GalleryImage(false, false , absolutePathOfImage, externalURI));
        }


        cursor.close();

        return listOfAllImages;
    }
}
```

And here in my fragment is where I am trying to delete the Images

```
 if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_selected){
                    //Uri root = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    for(GalleryImage i : mViewModel.selectedImages){
                        File file = new File(root + i.getmImageUrl());
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            if (file.delete()) {
                                System.out.println("file Deleted :" + file.getPath());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + file.getPath());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I tried like 4,5 different combinations but none of which seemed to work, I am trying to get the proper Path of the image, I saw that maybe using the `EXTERNAL_URI` would be the way to go but I don't know how to get it into my GalleryImage. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you add runtime permission? and what api you are using?

Comment: Please tell compile and target version and Android version of device used.

Comment: How did you obtain that path you are talking about to begin with?

Comment: `String externalURI = ""; //empty,  beacuse I couldnt get it to work...` Well get it to work as that is the uri you should use to delete file from media store too.

Comment: `File file = new File(root + i.getmImageUrl());` Please tell the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` for some images.

Comment: `String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();` That will never give a path like `/storage/1018-2710/.....` And why this construction? You have already `absolutePathOfImage` so use that.

Comment: `returns a URI not a String` Then use `URI:toString()`.

Comment: @Jerson I added permissions for ` WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" `  Alongside runtime permission, I am using MediaStore to fetch the data. 

@blackapps 29 version and target version 29, I got the path from the code above, the ImageLoader class. `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns `/storage/emulated/0/storage/1018-2710/Pictures/fQNV8jrdLO0.jpg`
Using the absolute path, yields me a result that the file doesn't exist. 
About your last comment `returns a URI not a String`, its not the porblem that I cannot parse the URi to String, but rather I cant use URI in projection.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void deleteSelectedImages(){
        for(GalleryImage img : selectedImages){
            File file = new File(img.getmImageUrl());
            if(!file.exists()) {
                return;
            }

            String canonicalPath;
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplication().getContentResolver();
            try {
                canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{canonicalPath});
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    contentResolver.delete(uri,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
                }
            }

            images.remove(img);
        }

        imagesLiveData.setValue(images);
        selectedImages.clear();
        Toast.makeText(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "Succesfully deleted image(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Hopefully it will help someone